# What is the best practise for testers that need to manage testing RESTful web services?

Tags: json, web-services, rest, testing

We have restful services which are produce JSON object, for developers they used to use POSTMAN/RESTCONSEle like tools via chrome browser, what about for testers?

What will be the best practise for testers to manage testing of these servies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For managed and automated testing of REST APIs, I would recommend [Runscope](https://www.runscope.com). If you're already a user of Postman, you can import your collections into Runscope, and schedule automated tests to fire from cloud (9 different locations) or even run tests on test/stage environments behind your firewall with the Runscope Radar Agent (https://www.runscope.com/docs/radar/agent).

Setting up test assertions is simple. Inspect JSON key existence/values, HTTP response codes, request times. You can also extract values from one request, stuff them into variables, and carry them over to subsequent requests. Variables can be used in other test assertions, in URIs/paths, parameters, headers, etc.

If you already have a good testing framework in place for other parts of your system, you can trigger Runscope tests with Trigger URLs (https://www.runscope.com/docs/radar/integrations). Additionally, after each test is complete, you can have Runscope POST that testing data to a webhook on your server (multiple webhooks are allowed), or access the test results via the API (https://www.runscope.com/docs/api/overview).

*Disclosure: I'm on the Runscope team, but I'm happy to help with anything related to APIs at any time.*

Answer (score 1):

Two recommendations:

1. **[curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)** is an excellent tool. [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) can be used on the command line which makes it an excellent option for scripting. Here's an example `POST` request with curl

   `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{first_name":"Harold","last_name":"Smith"}' http ://myhost:port/api/user`
2. **[Rest-assured](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/)**  is an excellent behavioral testing lib for Java that pairs well with existing Unit testing frameworks like [JUnit](http://junit.org/) and [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html). If you don't mind writing Java code, you can put together an excellent test suite for any REST api

RestClient's like POSTMan or RestClient are excellent tools, however such tools are *typically* not conducive to automation.

Comment: Rest-assured is looking good to try, RESTConsole, PostMAN tools are excellent like you said, but hard to manage automation with them.

Answer (score 0):

I used google rest client and it worked perfectly. They also provide API so that you can plugin there API in your custom code to enable automation.